# Why does an inverter circuit (NOT gate) need both a transistor and a complmentary transistor?

Tags: digital-logic

While reviewing logic gates, I read that to make an inverter circuit, you need two transitors, one of which is complementary, like so:

[image: http://www.cs.bu.edu/~best/courses/modules/Transistors2Gates/images/not-circuit.gif]

Assuming the intention of this circuit is to produce a NOT gate, then I ask:
Is the lower transistor necessary? Without it, it appears to me that the circuit would function just fine as a NOT gate.  If it is not necessary, is there a situation where it would be useful to have a second transitor?

Comment: Yes, there is a single complementary PMOS transistor (complementary to NMOS) in CMOS inverter. What is your question?

Comment: You may want to explain what your proposed alternative circuit actually is, then people can tell you whether it would work or why it would not work.

Comment: If you remove the lower transistor, Z = 0 for all values of X.

Comment: Really? why is that? (I'm not an engineer, not even a hobbyist, so please excuse my ignorance...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absence of voltage is *not* the same as zero volts in real circuits.

If you just have the top transistor, then you have a circuit that can source current but not sink it. If you need it to drive a PNP transistor - such as another copy of the same circuit - then it won't work properly.

You could have a PNP transistor and a pulldown (in1/out1), or an NPN transistor and a pullup (in2/out2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXb9a1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The latter is known as "open collector" and is quite common in TTL circuits.

Of course, having the resistor there consumes a certain amount of power when the transsitor is on, so using two transistors avoids that.

It's even more important with MOSFETs, as "no voltage connected" often turns into "voltage induced by nearby radio signals" or "whatever voltage was last connected to the gate capacitance".

Comment: I see, that makes sense. The purpose of the circuit is to supply power when x is false, and to SINK power when x is true. And using only a complimentary transistor will work, for certain applications...

Comment: This is know as open drain or open collector logic. Same logic used in I2C interface communication also.

Comment: @etothepowerofx no, it sinks or sources *current*. Either way, it is a power *source*. Your car engine, when in reverse, doesn't start producing unpower. It produces power which moves the car in the opposite direction.

Comment: There is no such thing as "absense of voltage". Any two points in the universe have a voltage. The difference here is the *impedance* between the points.

Comment: You just blew my mind with, "Absence of voltage is not the same as zero volts in real circuits."  Brand new hobbyist, and *now* I think I get it.

Answer (score 2):

In voltage-switching logic, there must be some means by which every node can be pulled up, and some means by which every node can be pulled down.  One could use a switching transistor for one of those functions and a resistor for the other, with the idea that when the transistor is "off" the resistor will be able to drive the line, but when the transistor is "on" it will overpower the resistor.  Such an approach used to be quite common, actually, in a technology called "NMOS" which used active pull-down transistors and passive pull-ups (within NMOS chips, the "pull-up resistor" would typically be form of transistor that's constructed in such fashion as to always be partially on, but it essentially works like a resistor).  The main problem with that approach is that a pull-up which doesn't pass much current will be slow to pull the wire high, and a pull-up which does pass a lot of current will burn a lot of power while the wire is pulled low.

In current-switching logic, if one didn't mind having to divide one's gates into two categories, such that each gate can only drive gates in the other category, one could get by with a single transistor for each inverting gate.  One category of gate would use NPN transistors and the other would use PNP.  A "high" signal feeding an NPN transistor would be represented by a positive current; a "high" feeding a PNP would be represented by a lack of negative current.  Since feeding current into the base of an NPN would cause its collector to sink current, a transistor would thus act like an inverter.  If one needs a signal from a gate in one category to be fed, inverted, to another gate of the *same* category one would need to use a transistor and resistor, in a fashion similar to the voltage-controlled logic above.